# Wrapping Collection Elements

Tags: oop, design-patterns

This is a design question and I'm going to frame it as clearly as possible, but I'm not really sure what to call the problem I'm facing.

I'm working on a video game, and setting up and playing the game involves multiple steps. I wanted to wrap each of these steps in some sort of object, to keep everything clean.

I chose to split up the flow of the game into sessions, rounds and spawns. A session of the game is the highest scope level, you configure which players are active (through a join screen) then proceed to start a round. You can play multiple rounds within a single session, and each of those rounds will inherit the global session data. Likewise, you can die and respawn multiple times in each round, inheriting data from both the round and the session.

So imagine somesort of free.

- Session 1
- Session 2

  - Round A
  - Round B

    - Spawn 1
    - Spawn 2
  - Round C
- Session 3

Spawn 1 will have access to data from Round B and Session 2.

This seems like a pretty clean design. I can keep the session-wide data in one place and keep that object alive through the entire session, with each round branching off and inheriting this data.

Now the interesting issue. Like I said before, the session contains a collection of players (the ones that joined the game and are active during the whole session). The round ALSO needs to keep some additional data about each player, but that data only exists inside a round (the last spawn point for instance, or the current score). I wanted to follow the same pattern and create another class, which would hold this round-specific data.

Where this breaks down is when maintaining the collections. Because the session contains the authoritative list on players, and each round provides additional add-on data, should the round just update a member of the SessionPlayer? Should the round have its own list of players, each with the round-level data and a pointer up to the session-level data? Should they contain separate collections with matching ids?

This seems like something that could be solved with a clever design pattern, but I haven't been able to find one.

To summarize: How to temporarily wrap an object containing a collection, while wrapping all the elements of that collection as well?

I hope I explained that properly. Thanks for the help!

Comment: How about having the `Player` object to carry all necessary data about himself? (Such as current session/round/spawn, HP, ammo, whatever)

Comment: Is this a MMOG where you have multiple sessions and rounds happening at the same time?

Comment: @tcarvin: Not an MMOG, but a game with local coop. Think something like Super Smash Bros

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your final question first:

> To summarize: How to temporarily wrap an object containing a collection, while wrapping all the elements of that collection as well?

This can be achieved with a [Composite Design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern), where a class contains elements of itself and the class can be stand-alone, or a container. Operations on this class will work on itself and on each of the elements it contains.

Regarding your previous questions about where to store the Players, this is a bit more difficult, but you should consider the following when deciding:

- The player data should indeed all be in one place. If you separate its ownership across different objects, that's a messy design and difficult to maintain.
- Try to avoid having pointers/references back and forth in your dependency hierarchy (Session, Round, Spawn) as this can get real complicated real quick, and it will no longer be a dependency hierarchy but instead a twisted mess of intertwined classes with very high coupling.
- If the player data is needed by all levels of the dependency hierarchy, then it should be contained somewhere that makes sense and is easily accessible by all levels of the hierarchy. If this is the case, you should also consider asking yourself if its really necessary that all levels need to know about the player data.

If its absolutely necessary to have these bi-directional references, then possibly the best way to implement it would be with [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). This will simplify the typical headaches involved with maintaining bi-directional references. Try to only inject the most specific entities needed, and not just the entire root-level object, like the Session.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, those are all good considerations.

I definitely agree about having bi-directional links. This is something I'm trying to avoid as much as possible.

I think the weird thing about this situation is that every level of the hierarchy DOES need to know about the players and the levels above, it also needs to add additional data. If I put all the Round and Spawn level data in the SessionPlayer class, then I have to manually control the lifetime of those members through some kind of ResetRound() or ResetSpawn() function.

Comment: Actually looking at the requirements, I don't think I can get away from bi-directional references. I need to have a tick signal go from the top of the hierarchy down to the children, but each child must know of its parent.

Comment: @deemen, I updated the answer with a way to do this, called Dependency Injection. Hopefully that will give you a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

So there are SessionPlayer and RoundPlayer classes. How about making RoundPlayer a nonstatic member class of SessionPlayer? This way, you can maintain 2 different collections, 1 for Session and 1 for Round with RoundPlayer implicitly having a reference to SessionPlayer.

Comment: This is kind of what I was thinking, but having two collections to maintain was tickling my code-sense. Maybe there's no other way though.